# I am stuck trying to figure out this formal proof. I need to prove (∃()→∀())→∀∀(()→())

Tags: logic, proof-writing

Using the Fitch application and only Intro and Elim rules (& REIT if necessary), prove that (∃()→∀())→∀∀(()→())
is a logical truth (i.e. prove it from no premises).
Have the Fitch program check your proof, then submit (to the D2L folder) a picture, screenshot or scan of a printed copy, showing the check marks.

Comment: Can you say more about what you're stuck on? Do you understand intuitively why this formula is true? Can you figure out which deduction rule must be used for the *last* step of your proof? (Hint: the desired sentence is of the form $A\to B$.)

Comment: I have no clue how to start this proof. Usually when I get started then I am good.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a semi-formal proof for you.

Suppose $\exists x P(x) \to \forall y Q(y)$.

Now suppose we have $P(c)$. Then by existential introduction, we have $\exists x P(x)$. Then we have $\forall y Q(y)$. Then in particular, we have $Q(d)$ by universal elimination.

Thus, we have $P(c) \to Q(d)$ by implication introduction. Then we have $\forall y (P(c) \to Q(y))$ by universal introduction. Then we have $\forall x \forall y (P(x) \to Q(y))$ by universal introduction.

Then we have $(\exists x P(x) \to \forall y Q(y)) \to \forall x \forall y (P(x) \to Q(y))$ by implication introduction.

Translated into Fitch, we have

Problem:  |- (((∃x)Px → (∀y)Qy) → (∀x)(∀y)(Px → Qy))

1   |_  ((∃x)Px → (∀y)Qy)                        Assumption
2   | |_  c                                      Flag
3   | | |_  d                                    Flag
4   | | | |_  Pc                                 Assumption
5   | | | |   (∃x)Px                             4  ∃I
6   | | | |   (∀y)Qy                             1,5  →E
7   | | | |   Qd                                 6  ∀E
8   | | |   (Pc → Qd)                            4-7  →I
9   | |   (∀y)(Pc → Qy)                          3-8  ∀I
10  |   (∀x)(∀y)(Px → Qy)                        2-9  ∀I
11    (((∃x)Px → (∀y)Qy) → (∀x)(∀y)(Px → Qy))    1-10  →I